# TakePicture without using a FileProvider

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fileprovider

I just want to take a picture and set it to an `ImageView`

I found two ways:

#### 1) Use `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture ()`

The problem with this method is that I have to create a file and pass the Uri to invoke the launcher. Since the new activity will not "belong" to my application, I have to use a FileProvider which requires modifying the manifest.xml and creating a new file: file_paths.xml

#### 2) Use `ActivityResultContract.TakePicturePreview ()`

With this option, I can avoid using FileProvider and the captured image is passed in a bitmap on the lambda function, like so:

```
    private val cameraLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()) { imageBitmap ->
            view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)?.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
}
```

The problem with this solution is that the returned `imageBitmap` is of very low quality.

### What I want

I just need to set the image in an ImageView. For this reason, in my data flux, this image should never be stored on disk. I don't want to use the first option, because I think the FileProvider overloads the code and I am creating a helper file that I will never use.

Is there a simple solution to get the full image without using a FileProvider?

Comment: "this image should never be stored on disk" -- full-resolution photos are large, which is why `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`/`ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture` requires them to be stored on disk, and that the "preview" approach (which avoids disk) results in a low-resolution image. "Is there a simple solution to get the full image without using a FileProvider?" -- not really. You could integrate CameraX or a third-party camera library and implement camera functionality yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with fileproviders and stuff if you access app specific dirs

Simply create a cache file with

```
new File(context.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "TemperoryFile_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
```

and File apis will work on it smoothly